# Anyonymous class, OnClickListener

Tags: java, android, listview

The following code used to try and generate a response when an item in a listView is selected.

The second @Override for onItemClick provides an error: *Method does not override method from is superclass*. If I comment it out "@Override", the app craches.

What do you do?

```
ListView receiptList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView_Items);
ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.simple_list_item_1, food_and_price);
receiptList.setAdapter(adapter);

receiptList.setOnClickListener(new AdapterView.OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

    }

    @Override // <--- this one!
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id){
        String data = price.get(position);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Well these two methods belong to two different interface hence you need to set them separately.

```
receiptList.setOnClickListener(new AdapterView.OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

    }
});

receiptList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
         String data = price.get(position);
    }
});
```